# How do I exclude a test in an Abstract Test (parent test class) in some children in JUnit?

Tags: junit

For example,
I have an `AbstractStorageTest` which has several tests including `storageOverflow`.
Children of that test class are `ArrayStorageTest`, `ListStorageTest`, `MapStorageTest`, `SortedStorageTest`.
Obviously `storageOverflow` is not applicable for Lists and Maps as they increase automatically when required.
How do I exclude `storageOverflow` test in `ListStorageTest`, `MapStorageTest`, and `SortedStorageTest` and leave it only in `ArrayStorageTest` where it is applicable to?

I overrode that test method in `ListStorageTest`, `MapStorageTest`, and `SortedStorageTest` making them pass successfully, but it does not seem to be the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating another abstract test class like `AbstractLimitedStorageTests` that extends `AbstractStorageTests` and serves as a new home for your `storageOverflow` test method. `ArrayStorageTest` than becomes a subclass of this new class.